# Mkraken give error like "EService:Unavailable".?

Tags: php, bitcoin

When I try to withdraw XBT from my account to other wallet address using Mkraken api it'll give me error like

**Error :**

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => EService:Unavailable
        )

)
```

Right now my account is verified upto tier2 and also having balance more then requested withdrawal btc.

but still it'll give an error anyone have an idea let me know..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply means that the function is currently not available. Reasons could be **maintenance at the backend** or similar.

Just wait for a few hours or a day. If it still does not work tomorrow you can contact Kraken support [here](https://support.kraken.com/hc/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

If you make too many requests per minute you can receive this message.Or try to create new API keys.